# After upgrading PHP to version 7, why can't I use the mongodb driver?

Tags: linux, php, mongodb

Well here's an odd situation I've found. I've been using PHP and MongoDB together on a project, and updated the associated software. After the upgrade, I did make sure to update the new conf files and all is well --- except when I try to use the `MongoClient` class, I get the following fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in /srv/http/test.php

So my first instinct was to check my `/etc/php/php.ini` to make sure that mongodb.so was correctly included. I found it after the other `extension` lines:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=zip.so
extension=mongodb.so ; <--- here it is
```

With that checked, I loaded up a quick `phpinfo()` script to check that I was using the right `php.ini` file, and confirmed that I am. And not only that, the mongodb driver also appears to be loaded correctly!

```
Loaded Configuration File      /etc/php/php.ini

mongodb support                enabled
mongodb                        version      1.1.1
mongodb                        stability    stable
libmongoc                      version      1.3.1-dev
libbson                        version      1.3.0
```

So I restarted httpd and tried again. No dice, still can't find the `MongoClient` class. So I tried to install it from `pecl` instead of my distribution's package manager, and the situation is the same as described above.

---

So here's a quick rundown of the situation:

- Linux kernel 4.3.3
- PHP Version 7.0.1
- php-mongodb version 1.1.1

  - Yes, [1.1.1 supports php7](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases).
- Seems properly configured, and mongodb is enabled and shown in `phpinfo()`.
- Tried installing the mongodb driver through `pecl` and my distro's package manager.

Other info that may be useful:

- MongoDB Version 3.2.0
- `mongod` is running
- Also tried rebooting, no change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I found the answer.

The class has been changed. It's no longer `\MongoClient`, and is now `\MongoDB\Driver\Manager`

All that I need is a refactor. The new driver is designed to be a lower-level driver for high-level functionality to be filled with userspace libraries, so anyone else upgrading to php7, make sure you check that you'll be comfortable with the new driver, or that the userspace libraries exist when you do it. Hopefully this question/answer helps others in the future.

Here's one of the big Mongo libraries to use for PHP now: [mongo-php-library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library).

Comment: Thanks for that, man, you saved me another day of googling.

Answer (score 3):

As you mention, the class structure to interact with MongoDB from PHP7 has changed and you would need to refactor your code (a lot depending on how it was initially planned and written).

One solution that you might want to look into is https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter

I've noticed that in most cases including the adapter library is all you need to do in order to have your old PHP5 code work properly.

Then I'd strongly suggest that you migrate your code to the new MongoDB PHP Library (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) or that you use the native driver to benefit from the speed gains.

Comment: Oh man, the adapter is a great find.

Comment: The adapter is so great!! Saved my time (although I've already started to refactor the legacy PHP code in our base)

Comment: I'd suggest not using this adapter as a crutch to avoid refactoring for too long, adding a layer on top of another layer just adds complexity, potential for bugs, and less performant.

Comment: Thanks @mike-purcell ! Your comment makes the last paragraph of my answer more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

- First we need to install MongoDB in the machine through the steps mentioned in official MongoDB website
- The next step is to install a MongoDB drive to use with PHP.
- The MongoDB driver for PHP Version 5.99.99 or older was:
  package/mongo
  to install this we need to use:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev

  sudo pecl install mongo
  ```
- From PHP 7 onwards, this is the new driver
  package/mongodb To install that use: `sudo pecl install mongodb`
- If you are using Laravel framework or projects with composer, then this library is the most apt one:
  https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB
  Use version 3.0.0 to get PHP 7 & Laravel 5 support and otherwise use the older version 2.2.2
  Composer command:

  ```
  composer require jenssegers/mongodb
  ```
- If you are using other PHP frameworks without composer, use this library: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library which is also used in the above mentioned library